# Product of distants from 1 to the corner of n gonal inscribe inside a unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $P_j=\cos \frac{2\pi}{n}+i\cos \frac{2\pi}{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Show that

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}|P_j-P_0|=n.$$

Answer (score 1):

We know $P_j$ are the order-n roots of unity. Hence $$(z-P_0)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(Z-P_i)\equiv z^n-1.$$ Let us differentiate with respect to $z$: $$-P_0\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(z-P_i)+(z-P_0)\frac{d}{dz} \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(z-P_i) \equiv n z^{n-1}.$$ Taking $z=P_0=1$ gives:$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(P_0-P_i)=-n$$, hence the result follows.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried to solve it by using the identity of trigonometry but it was messy. This is clever.

Comment: Welcome! PS: since you accept my solution, would you give it accordingly the points? Thanks!